# is apache James compatible with arm64

Tags: apache-httpd, software-compatibility, mail-server

I am trying to set up a apache james mail server on my raspberry pi 4
https://james.apache.org/server/quick-start.html
but i get this error when i run the ./james

```
schmax@ubuntu:~/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin$ ./james
Unable to locate any of the following operational binaries:
  /home/schmax/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin/./wrapper-linux-aarch64-64
  /home/schmax/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin/./wrapper-linux-aarch64-32
  /home/schmax/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin/./wrapper (Found but not executable.)

schmax@ubuntu:~/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin$ ./james start
Unable to locate any of the following operational binaries:
  /home/schmax/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin/./wrapper-linux-aarch64-64
  /home/schmax/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin/./wrapper-linux-aarch64-32
  /home/schmax/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin/./wrapper (Found but not executable.)
schmax@ubuntu:~/james/james-server-app-3.6.0/bin$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that it *can* work on a Pi.

However, it looks to me like james is not pure java and so that package includes pre-built binaries.  They will be compiled for x86(-64) and will not work on any model of Pi.

You need to start with the "Source code" version from here: https://james.apache.org/download.cgi#Apache_James_Server

There is documentation for doing that:

https://james.apache.org/server/install.html

You need to follow the *"If you have downloaded a source package, process* [sic] *first to the **build**..."* track; the "build" link is:

https://james.apache.org/server/dev-build.html

Comment: thx man works grade

Comment: Cheers.  If this did work for you please tick the big checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue when attempting to run Apache James on my Raspberry Pi.

I'm using Apache James 3.7.2 with Spring wiring.

The `bin/james` script uses a wrapper to kick off the Java process from Tanuki software.

https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com

Presumably this is for convenience when trying to run James as a service. If you have a look through `conf/wrapper.conf` it configures the wrapper to run the `JamesAppSpringMain` Java class.

There is an alternative script provided in the distribution - `bin/run.sh`.
This script also executes the same Java class `JamesAppSpringMain` but without using the service wrapper.

I found that using the `bin/run.sh` script works fine on my Raspberry Pi without any problems.

Another option is to download the Linux ARM (AArch64) version of the service wrapper. The Tanuki website does list the 64 bit version as being available.

https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp#stable

I haven't tried this as I was satisfied using the `bin/run.sh` script.